# layoutinflater nullpointerexception in android

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, layout-inflater, android-framelayout

I want to set `Activity` in `FrameLayout`. Here is my code:

```
FrameLayout fl = new FrameLayout(this);
fl = (FrameLayout ) findViewById(R.id.actioncontent);           
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);           
View myview =LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.wallpaper, null);
fl.removeAllViews();
fl.addView(myview);
```

I am getting an error **NullPointerException**.

Comment: View myview =LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.wallpaper, null); change this to View myview =inflater.inflate(R.layout.wallpaper, null);

Comment: Thank you  well i got it i solve this error now i have another issue i want to show an activity in this frame-layout and activity name is Wallpaper how can i show this activity in frame-layout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
```

to

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `inflator` insteed of `LayoutInflater.from(this)`

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            View myview =LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.wallpaper, null);
            fl.removeAllViews();
                fl.addView(myview);
```

Replace above code with below

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            View myview =inflater .inflate(R.layout.wallpaper, null);
            fl.removeAllViews();
                fl.addView(myview);
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't state what 'this' was, or where the NPE is happening - but it could be that 'this' presents the wrong context.
Try using your activity name instead? For instance, `MainActivity.this`

Also, as was stated below me, replace from `View myview =LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate` to `View myview = inflater.inflate`